# load more feature or endless pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I recently learnt I need pagination otherwise page won't load faster.
so I implemented it. 
But now that I finished implemented, I realize I have some problem.
My web has a format like this
[image]

The above is the top part of the page
[image]

and the above is the below part of the page.

all my posts are going into the below part, and because more posts I write more posts will be there I implemented pagination.

the pagination works fine, but when I go to the next page the top part remains there while the below part shows new posts. (I have implemented this without realizing the existence of the top part)
I don't want my users to see the top part every time they click next page.

I think I have two ways to solve this problem.
One is to somehow not show the top part when they click next page.

Or 
I use load more button to show more posts instead of going into another page.

Problem is I don't know how to do either one of them..can some one please help me?

```
def category_detail(request, slug):

    obj = NewsCategory.objects.get(slug=slug)
    newsInCat = obj.news_set.all() #for the list of news
    paginator = Paginator(newsInCat, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        news_set = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        news_set = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        news_set = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    bestInCat = obj.news_set.get_bestInCat()


    context = {
        "obj":obj, 
        "news_set":news_set,
        "newsInCat":newsInCat,
        "bestInCat":bestInCat,

    }
    return render(request, "news/category_detail.html", context)    



<div class="row">
<div>
{% for news in news_set %}
  <div class='col-sm-4'>

    <div class="content">
    <figure class="story-image">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'><img src="{{news.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="360" height="267"></a>
    </figure>
      <div id="forever "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}' style="text-decoration:none; color:#282E5C;"><h4 style="font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;">{{news.title}}</h4></a>
  </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        <!-- {% if news_set.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ news_set.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ news_set.number }} of {{ news_set.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span> -->

        {% if news_set.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ news_set.next_page_number }}">Load More</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) in the html you can show top block if page number equals 1. For example

```
{% if news_set.number==1%}
    {{ top_block}}
{% endif %}
<div class="row">
<div>
{% for news in news_set %}
  <div class='col-sm-4'> ....
```

2) you can render partial html if request is ajax

Here is simple code

**views.py**

```
def category_detail(request, slug):
    obj = NewsCategory.objects.get(slug=slug)
    newsInCat = obj.news_set.all() #for the list of news
    paginator = Paginator(newsInCat, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        news_set = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        news_set = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            news_set = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    if request.is_ajax():
        context = {
            'news_set':news_set
        }
        return render(request,"news/category_detail_ajax.html",context)
    else:
        bestInCat = obj.news_set.get_bestInCat()
        context = {
          "obj":obj, 
          "news_set":news_set,
          "newsInCat":newsInCat,
          "bestInCat":bestInCat,
        }
        return render(request, "news/category_detail.html", context)
```

**category_detail_ajax.html**

```
{% for news in news_set %}
  <div class='col-sm-4'>

    <div class="content">
    <figure class="story-image">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'><img src="{{news.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="360" height="267"></a>
    </figure>
      <div id="forever "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}' style="text-decoration:none; color:#282E5C;"><h4 style="font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;">{{news.title}}</h4></a>
  </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

**javascript**

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.load-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:jQuery(this).attr('href')
    }).done(function(data){
        jQuery('.row>div').append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you I tried both, I completely understood the first one and that one worked like a charm but I kinda unerstood the second one and that one doesn't do anything....which one is a superior of which? I would guess second but why??

Comment: You can use or 1) or 2). For 2 one you must make some changes like change url of button, add css class to load more button etc. I gave you just direction not full the map :)

Comment: I'm going with the first one then ;)